# Get the exact match using fnFilter() for multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I am using `fnFilter()` to filter the values as shown below. If I select 2 check-boxes to filter my searchString would be --> `Inprogress|Delivered`

```
 searchText =  "Inprogress|Delivered";
 oTable.fnFilter(searchText,18,true, false);
 //oTable.fnFilter("^"+searchText+"$", 18, true, false);
```

However I have another value in my Table `Inprogress and ready` which is also getting filtered because I have selected `Inprogress`.

Please help me how can avoid this situation because I want to get the exact match even if I select multiple values to filter.

Thanks in Advance. Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with slight modification

```
searchText =  "(Inprogress|Delivered)";
oTable.fnFilter(searchText+"$",18,true, false);
```

$ to specify end of search text. 18 is column number is above code